# Android How to generate a String Vector Path for Circle Rotation

Tags: android, vector

I want to develop an App in which **bubbles are rotating outside of a Name**.
So for that purpose i want a circle Rotation in Vector Format.

Thank in Advance for Help.

Answer (score 3):

just Add vector path in string.xml .

```
<string name="circle">

M527.023,71.8233 C780.213,71.8233,985.464,277.075,985.464,530.265
C985.464,783.455,780.213,988.707,527.023,988.707
C273.832,988.707,68.5809,783.455,68.5809,530.265
C68.5809,277.075,273.832,71.8233,527.023,71.8233 Z
```

its working.[image: check image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
Its working for me :D